# Post items in a collection to Spring Data Rest api

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, typescript, api

My api looks like this at http://localhost:8080/api/projects/13/employees :

```
{
  "_embedded": {
     "employees": []
  },
  "_links": {
     "self": {
     "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/13/employees"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
addEmployeesToProject(projectId: number, employees: IEmployee[]): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
// i tried even without /employees or put method
    return this.httpClient.post<IEmployee[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${projectId}/employees`, // i tried even without /employees 
      employees
    );
  }
```

And also something like this for the post<> :

```
interface GetProjectEmployeesResponse {
  _embedded: {
    employees: IEmployee[];
  };
}
```

But they dont get added.
How do i add employees to the employees: [] collection?

Comment: `{_embedded: {employees}}` instead of `employees` in post body.

Comment: I tried this but now it get this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/projects/4' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I already have @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200") in my ProjectRepository

Comment: You missing `employees` in endpoint url

Comment: return this.httpClient.post<IEmployee[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${projectId}/employees`, {
      _embedded: { employees },
    });
I tried this code.


Now the error is gone but i keep receiving null back and so the employee are not added. I have no error in chrome nor in spring console. Im sorry im new.